# Regarding a Javascript HTTP POST request?

Tags: javascript, php, http, post

If I have a website with a piece of java-script added on to the page - e.g. when a visitor clicks on a button - it sends a HTTP request to an external URL.

If the external URL (who receives this request) tries to check the IP address/host of where it came from -- Would this show the visitor's IP or the original website's IP?

Comment: It will show the visitors IP since it is a client side request. To pass along credentials across domains you'll have to use something like tokens.

Comment: @25r43q Ah right ok, thank you! - I have thought further into this - would using the PHP $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] be suitable? Would this always return the URL/page where the request was made from? (The 'external website' would check this rather than it being passed over)

Answer (score 0):

If the request is sent from the client-side via JavaScript, it is a HTTP request send from the user's computer.

For this reason, **the host will also see the public IP address of the user's computer**. In this regard, it is very similar to the user simply copying the URL into the browser's address bar or to opening it via a click on a link on the web site.

Note that the result may vary though, e.g. if the request was routed through a proxy.